# How do I convert an MK3D file into an MKV file while preserving the 3D?

Tags: video, video-conversion, matroska, 3d, oculus-rift

I have an MK3D video file containing a 3D movie.  But my video player ([Skybox](https://skybox.xyz/en/) for Oculus Quest) does not support MK3D files, only MKV files.  My question is, how do I convert my MK3D file into an MKV file, while keeping it as a 3D video?

Both MKV and MK3D are part of the [Matroska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) file format, so I tried simply renaming the file from “.mk3d” to “.mkv”.  But that makes it play as a 2D movie, it loses the 3D aspect.  So how do I preserve the 3D nature of the file?

Comment: Renaming the file does not lose any 3D info and the problem is just with the player. Some players can be manually set to play `.mkv` files in 3D mode, as the file-extension difference is just a convenience feature to put the player into the right mode. If Skybox doesn't support that, there is a list of supporting players in [this article](https://extension.nirsoft.net/mk3d), to which you should add [VLC](https://videoconverter.wondershare.com/multimedia-tips/play-3d-movies-with-vlc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the file does not lose any 3D info and the problem is just with the player.

The file-extension difference between `.mkv` and `.mk3d` is just a convenience feature
as a hint to the player in which mode to do the play, as the file-format is the
same for both.

Players that can play both formats usually have a menu setting that can manually
set to play `.mkv` files in 3D mode, or `.mk3d` in 2D mode.

If Skybox doesn't support playing `.mk3d` and has no such menu entry, then it
just does not support 3D play, so it is time to switch player.

I would suggest the free and open source cross-platform multimedia player
[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)
as an excellent player.
See the article
[3 Useful Tips for Playing 3D Movies with VLC](https://videoconverter.wondershare.com/multimedia-tips/play-3d-movies-with-vlc.html).

You will also find a list of 3D players in the nirsoft article
[.mk3d Extension - List of programs that can open .mk3d files](https://extension.nirsoft.net/mk3d).

Comment: I looked it up and apparently, it seems it is supported, it just does not recognize the .mk3d file extension.

Comment: Really supported means that you should have some menu option for playing `.mkv` in 3D mode.

Comment: There is - `Support All  Stereo Modes
SKYBOX supports all stereo modes, whether it is 2D or 3D, 180°or 360°. You can set stereo mode and various other parameters easily in SKYBOX.` This is from their website

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no conversion needed, as .mkv and .mk3d are in the same container. All you have to do is change the file extension in File Explorer from FileName.mk3d to Filename.mkv and open it up in Skybox. As for support in Skybox, I found this article here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/351815/how-to-stream-vr-videos-and-movies-to-oculus-go-from-pc-or-mac/

This shows how to add a VR/3D file into Skybox, as shown in the article:

> How to Fix Movies If They Don’t Play in the Right Format: If you’ve got
>   a 3D or VR video that isn’t playing in 3D or VR, you can fix that by
>   pulling up the controls. Just click once, and then click the little
>   cube on the far right of the menu. This pops up a window with options
>   for playing in 2D, 3D, or VR mode (and for switching between VR 180
>   and VR 360). If you’re not sure of the exact format of your video,
>   just keep testing until it looks right.
>   Hope this helps!